# GraphQL Apollo Server v3 Production PubSUB Library

Tags: javascript, heroku, graphql, apollo-server

I have tried to google for this but I think the best answer can come from someone who already used some Production PubSub library. So if you have ever used any of the following production PubSub library with Apollo Server Version 3 please share your experience and help fellow developers choose the right one for their apps.

1. Redis
2. Kafka
3. RabbitMQ

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ This question is off-topic for this site because it is seeking opinions rather than direct answers to specific questions about code _ Please visit SO Help Center section on 'Asking' and specifically this article about 'What topics can I ask about here?' >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hey ! did you find the answer ? I too want to findout which is better to use. I am also trying to integrate graphql-google-pubsub in my project but nothing's working.

Comment: If you need real time updates like the ones appear on facebook then Redis is the best option. Otherwise, you can use Kafka or RabbitMQ depending upon your usecase.